# How to make an input go to next line when reaching its width HTML

Tags: html, css

so I am trying to do something reasonably simple, I have an 'input' on my website which has a width of 1000px. However once you have filled that line, I want the input to then go to the next line down instead of running off the text box.

For example I want this:
[image]

To look like this:

[image]

I am not really sure what the correct term is for this, so sorry if its confusing and messy.

Thanks :)

Comment: You are looking for text area not input

Comment: Is there not an alternative? I am using this as a form and it works fine as it is, is there no simple css style or something to fix this?

Comment: Is there a problem with using textarea instead of input? It does look as though textarea is what you need.

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't do that with an `<input>`. This is what `<textarea>` is for.

Comment: Am I correct in saying then, that if I simply change my input to textarea, the form it is inside of will still pick this up?

Comment: @Lukeyy Your correct, if you replace the `<input>` with a `<textarea>` in your form, long words will be broken and wrap onto a new line. The `overflow-wrap` property is by default added to textarea elements and this is what makes content in a `<textarea>` wrap onto new lines.

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend replacing your `<input>` element with a  [`<textarea>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea) in the form. This way, any text that overflows the `<textarea>`'s content box will wrap onto the next line. The default styling for `<textarea>` elements in the User Agent Stylesheet contain `overflow-wrap: break-word;` which allows long words to be broken and wrap onto the next line.

> [`overflow-wrap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap) property applies to inline elements, setting whether the browser should insert line breaks within an otherwise unbreakable string to prevent text from overflowing its line box.

Unfortunately, there isn't a well-defined way to do this for `<input>` elements.

```css
.my-form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-width: 1000px;
}

.my-form textarea {
  border: .2rem solid #000;
  resize: vertical; /* control in which direction textarea can be resized */
}
```

```html
<form class="my-form">
  <label for="msg">Write message</label>
  <textarea id="msg" name="msg" rows="5" cols="50">SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS</textarea>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

try to use textarea field for this. Using input text field is not a good idea

```css
.textarea-custom
{
  min-height:150px;
  max-height:250px;
  min-width:100%;
  max-width:100%;
}
```

```html
<textarea class="textarea-custom" placeholder="Enter text here..." rows="" cols="" name="" form="">
sssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss
</textarea>
```